# How do I remove Facebook app showing in my Facebook app page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app and it has a Facebook app page. I would like to keep the Facebook app available and live, but I would like to remove the app showing in the app Facebook page.

If I remove the app tab from "Settings" and "Apps", does this still keep the app alive, but only removes it from the page tabs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go settings, then app on the left side off your screen. then if you take your courser on that app then a wrong symbol will appear click on it, it will be deleted.

Comment: n no it doesn't keep the app alive .